# Fancybox makes unwanted synchronous request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox-2

i have formular, which i want to submit via ajax. There fore i am using the [jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit). well, this works fine.

i receive an html page as result und want to pass it to a [fancybox (v2.0)](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/). but if i am going to open the fancybox i receive this wellknown chrome warning:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

hence, i wonder about two things:

1. why does this warning appear, because whether the fancybox neither my ajax request uses `async = false` or the like. well, that is as far as i know, and i checked source code of fancybox, so...
2. why do i get the following error, when i try to submit the form a second time?

   > Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ajaxSubmit is not a function.

   i have the feeling, that after the warning appeared, the function that causes the warning is removed from the context and hence not callable ... ?!

if i do not use fancybox - when i for instance just call `console.log(result)` - i do not get the error. so something must wrong with fancybox, i guess.

why don't i directly call the url of the page i want to load in the content of the fancybox, as normal people would do it? well, because fancybox has no options to pass post data to the url, hence i need to submit the form.
sending get-data is out of the question.

---

here is the problematic code :)

```
$(domObject).ajaxSubmit({
    dataType: "html",
    success:  function(result) {
        $.fancybox.open({
            padding:    0,
            margin:     0,
            content:    result,
            autoSize:   false
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out, that if there are script tags with a src attribute in the content you are passing to fancybox, then the error appears.

i guess, that the fancybox buffers the content and waits until all the javascript files are loaded... but this is just a bad guess, because on link tags with href attribute the behavior does not occur.

at the moment i can easily bypass the problem, but i will open an issue for fancybox.

Comment: well, scripts inside an ajax call may always conflict with other scripts in your main page

Answer (score -1):

Try to use below code:

```
$(domObject).ajaxSubmit({
   dataType: "html",
   async: true,
   success:  function(result) {
     $.fancybox(result, {
        padding:    0,
        margin:     0,
        content:    result,
        autoSize:   false
     });
   }
});
```

Comment: the ajax request is not the problem. the async parameter is true, by default. also, when i remove the code opening the fancybox, no warnings/errors appear

Comment: I was also facing same issue but able to fix it by putting async: true. I know it is by default true but it works when I write it explicitly